# Swift | Show image in Custom GMSMarker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

[image: custom Marker with user profile pics]

I want to show user's profile picture in my custom marker for google maps. Like all others, I have tried this code in `init:` of customMarker

```
self.location = location
position = location
icon = UIImage(named: "live location")
groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
```

Is there any possible way to show another image in the circle of the marker icon. ex. using xib.

Comment: You can do this by making a custom class of `UIView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use given two methods:

```
func drawImageWithProfilePic(pp: UIImage, image: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    let imgView = UIImageView(image: image)
    let picImgView = UIImageView(image: pp)
    picImgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

    imgView.addSubview(picImgView)
    picImgView.center.x = imgView.center.x
    picImgView.center.y = imgView.center.y - 7
    picImgView.layer.cornerRadius = picImgView.frame.width/2
    picImgView.clipsToBounds = true
    imgView.setNeedsLayout()
    picImgView.setNeedsLayout()

    let newImage = imageWithView(view: imgView)
    return newImage
}

func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
    var image: UIImage?
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        view.layer.render(in: context)
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    return image ?? UIImage()
}
```

Here `pp` is your profile pic and `image` is the pic icon.
You can set the frame of Profile pic according to you.
I have tried this:

**Edit**

```
let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
marker.icon = drawImageWithProfilePic(pp: imgPP, image: img)
marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
marker.map = viewGoogleMap
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Where do u want me to use `view.addSubview(imageView)` because `GMSMarker` is not allowing to use `addSubview`

Comment: `drawImageWithProfilePic(pp: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_pic"), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pin_short"))` will return an image. You just need to set it on your marker's icon.

Answer (score 2):

```
    //put this code where you get image

     let url = URL(string: "your_imageUrlString")
     let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

      let marker = GMSMarker()
       marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat)!, longitude:  Double(long)!)
   marker.icon = self.drawImageWithProfilePic(pp: UIImage.init(data:data!)!, image: UIImage.init(named: "red")!)
       marker.title = location
          marker.snippet = name + " " + mobile
    marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
                                marker.map = self.mapView


//put this code in your viewController class 
 func drawImageWithProfilePic(pp: UIImage, image: UIImage) -> UIImage {

        let imgView = UIImageView(image: image)
         imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

        let picImgView = UIImageView(image: pp)
        picImgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)

        imgView.addSubview(picImgView)
        picImgView.center.x = imgView.center.x
        picImgView.center.y = imgView.center.y - 7
        picImgView.layer.cornerRadius = picImgView.frame.width/2
        picImgView.clipsToBounds = true
        imgView.setNeedsLayout()
        picImgView.setNeedsLayout()

        let newImage = imageWithView(view: imgView)
        return newImage
    }

    func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
        var image: UIImage?
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            view.layer.render(in: context)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
        return image ?? UIImage()
    }



//here "red" is dummy background image
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create/design a custom view either in `nib` or `programmatically` and then assign it to your marker like this.

```
let someView = YourCustomView()
someView.markerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "markerImage")
someView.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "userImage")

let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.map = yourMapView
marker.position = somePositionCoordinate;
marker.iconView = someView
```

Comment: There is no property `customView` for GMSMarker, we only have `iconView`. Using `iconView` is not helping.